# Reg Delete with subkey

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I'm getting an error when I try to delete a registry key in a .bat file:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\SHC" /v "    69    REG_MULTI_SZ    C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\UltraVNC\UltraVNC Server Settings.lnk\0C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\uvnc_settings.exe" /f
```

The error I am getting is:

```
    ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

I am running from a user that has administrator rights and I run it as administrator.

This link shows what the sub key looks like:
[image]

Comment: You don't specify the value data in `reg delete`, just the value name. `reg delete HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\SHC /v 69`

Comment: The value data is in quotes after the /v " 69 REG_MULTI_SZ C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\UltraVNC\UltraVNC Server Settings.lnk\0C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\uvnc_settings.exe"

Comment: ... and that is improper syntax for the `reg delete` command! After `/v` you only specify the value name. Look at the examples under `reg delete/?`.

Comment: Perhaps in my first comment I should have used the praising "You should not specify..." rather than *you don't specify..."1

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I have a cmd that currently gives me the value name and the value data in the same variable.  How can I separate the value name?

Comment: Set "Key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\SHC"
Set "Str=uvnc bvba"
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "EOL=E Delims=" %%I in ('@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "%Key%" /v * ^| find "%Str%"') do (Echo=reg delete "%Key%" /v "%%~I" /f 2>nul
for /F "EOL=E Delims=" %%I in ('@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "%Key%" /v * ^| find "%Str%"') do (@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe delete "%Key%" /v "%%I" /f
     if not errorlevel 1 echo Deleted "%%~I" from "%Key%" >>%~dpn0.txt 
   echo %%~I >>%~dpn0Str.txt
)
endlocal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to my cmd line.

```
@Echo Off
Set "Key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UFH\SHC"
Set "Str=uvnc bvba"
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
If exist %~dpn0.txt del %~dpn0.txt
If exist %~dpn0Str.txt del %~dpn0Str.txt
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%A in ('@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "%Key%" /v * ^| find "%Str%"') DO @(Echo=@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe delete "%Key%" /v "%%A" /f
if not errorlevel 1 echo Deleted "%%A" from "%Key%" >>%~dpn0.txt 
echo %%C >>%~dpn0Str.txt
)
endlocal
cmd /k
```

This gives me the subkey name in %%A
This gives me the subkey data in %%C

```
Note: Echo= before the reg delete needs to be removed for it to execute
Note: This must be run as administrator
```